Root user issue in data recovery program
I am trying to get to run data recovery apps PhotoRec and TestDisc on my Mac mini / M2 with Ventura 13.3 but I keep getting the error message
YOU MUST BE ROOT TO USE THIS PROGRAM despite the fact that I am the principal and the only user of my Mac.
Could anyone kindly advise what might be the problem? I can do very basic things in Terminal following instructions but I am not too familiar with code ...
Thanks

Use "sudo" before the command in Terminal. It will ask for your password.

I tried but "sudo testdisk" or "sudo photorec" are rejected as invalid commands. I am currently lauching these apps out of the regular finder window by executing the testdisk file in the folder unzipped from the program download. What would be the proper command to lauch it directly from Terminal?
